# Output ends with '%' sign

Tags: python

So I am python newbie currently working on making a basic random password generator in python. It takes an integer as an input for the length of a password that the user would like. It then outputs a random string of text. For example if the user enters 8, it will return a random set of 8 characters. The issue I am having is that it returns random characters, but it appends a random % sign at the end of them. I think it might just be a shell prompt from Zsh randomly appending itself there, but I'm not too sure. If anybody has any idea on why it would be appending it self there, or how to format the output to remove it, I would greatly appreciate it. I am currently using Fedora 36 with Z shell.

Code:

```
import random
import string

print('How many characters would you like your password to be?:')

passwd_length = int(input())
random_chars = (string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)

for i in range(0,passwd_length):
    
    i = random.choice(random_chars)
    print(i,end = '')
```

(User enters 8)

Output:

```
:/VG#DYQ%
```

(User enters 10)

Output:

```
Hqo64w"H"l%
```

Comment: can you try adding a `print()` after the loop ends ? Or remove the loop and do `print("".join(random.choices(random_chars, passwd_length)))`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol

Comment: @azro So adding that empty `print()` statement at the end worked, thank you. I read the post that @jonrsharpe linked and tried messing around with the .zshrc configuration file, to get it to act more like traditional shells, but no avail.